# Sometimes an inline style's background-position-x or y attribute is not being set

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I render a component, it's `props` shows that it has the correct values, but the div element it generates is missing either it's `background-position-x` or `background-position-y`.

I do something like the following in a parent class:

```
//Class ImageSelector is roughly:
onClick() {
    this.state.image = randomlySelectImage()
}

render() {
     return <ItemIcon image={this.state.image}/>
}
```

The Icon in question:

```
class Icon extends React.component
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.image)

    let style = {
        width: 48,
        height: 48,
        background: `url('./img/${this.props.image.sprite}')`,
        backgroundPositionX: -this.props.image.x,
        backgroundPositionY: -this.props.image.y
    }

    return <div style={style}/>;
}
```

When the fudgeup happens, the React dev tools shows that Icon indeed has the appropriate values available `x = 192` and `y = 384`, and even the div's `style` is showing the correct values, while the div element on inspection looks like the following: `url("./img/sprite0.png") -384px`. The `x` value is missing, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure it's not undefined, null or some other falsy value?

Comment: Yes. React Dev tools shows the following on the div in question: http://i.imgur.com/427qf1w.png

Comment: This isn't a great answer so I'll just add it as a comment, but does `backgroundPosition: this.props.x + "px" + " " + this.props.y + "px"` work?

Comment: Gross, but that is working mostly (error rate is down by ~99%).

However every once and a while, the `backgroundPosition` prop isn't included in the element's style much like the X or Y wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the original problem seems to have no solution (as least as of React v15.3.2), the workaround has ended up being specifying the `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY` as part of the `background` property.

```
class Icon extends React.component
  render() {
    let style = {
      width: 48,
      height: 48,
      background: `url('./img/${this.props.image.sprite}') ${-this.props.image.x}px ${-this.props.image.y}px`
    }

    return <div style={style}/>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the game, but there's no solution to your question: your inline style is ambiguous. Specifically, [React tries to optimize style properties (issue 5030)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5030), but fails when both shorthand properties (`background`) and full properties (`background-position`) are present.

The easiest solution is to not use shorthand properties:

```js
 - background: `url('./img/${this.props.image.sprite}')`,
 + backgroundImage: `url('./img/${this.props.image.sprite}')`,
   backgroundPositionX: -this.props.image.x,
   backgroundPositionY: -this.props.image.y
```